# The Application can't find the Json value in Mac OS

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I want to reach a value which in a basic JsonObject but the application doesn't work in Mac OS. However i can use this application on Windows. 
When I run the application, I have an error in genymotion "Unfortunately, the application is stopped". And I have errors in Log, too.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
TextView txt;
Button btn;

String adi="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new veriler().execute();
        }
    });
}

public class veriler extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSonParseSinifi nesne=new JSonParseSinifi();
        JSONObject json;
        json=nesne.JSonObjeAl("http://localhost/android_connect/create_product.php");
        try {
                adi=json.getString("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Catch bloğu", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        txt.setText(adi);
    }
```

My application works on Windows. I have true JSonParser class. Application is not broken. I don't understand why the application doesn't work properly on my Mac.

Comment: You are using server at localhost. Are you sure the server is running under Mac OS and giving right response?

Comment: Show JSON string which getting in `json`

Comment: Your error is on 'adi=json.getString("success")'. Looking for the string `success` is null. So my suggestion would be checking your php script on your Mac and seeing what kind of JSON returns. Try in another application outside of Android or eclipse

Comment: My response is; {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}. PHP code has true working.